# How to float inline elements with css

Tags: html, css

lets say i have the following markup:

```
<ul class="editor">
<li> 
  <a href="#">Modules</a>
  <a href="#">View</a>
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</li>
<li> 
  <a href="#">Sections</a>
  <a href="#">View</a>
  <a href="#">Add</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

how do i float 'view' and 'add' to the right so that the right so that they appear in the same order as the html?

right now if i do

```
.editor li a:nth-child(2), .editor li a:nth-child(3){
  float:right;
}
```

i will get a row that looks like:

```
Modules                           Add View
```

but i want

```
Modules                           View Add
```

Is this possible just via **CSS3**?

**edit**:
sorry i should have mentioned, i dont have access to the html. only css

Comment: Each `li` is in its own row, right? (You clear the floats, etc.)

Comment: Anything you float automatically becomes block level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text-align the `li` right and float only the 1st `a` left.

```
.editor li {
  text-align: right; 
}
.editor li a:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}
```

*I assume that you've already hidden the default list bullets*.

Comment: I realize the question asks "just via CSS3", but... `a:first-child` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order.

```
<ul class="editor">
<li> 
  <a href="#">Modules</a>
  <a href="#">Add</a>
  <a href="#">View</a>
</li>
<li> 
  <a href="#">Sections</a>
  <a href="#">Add</a>
  <a href="#">View</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned, i dont have access to the html. only css

Answer (score 1):

Try the CSS3 flexible box model with explicit distribution and the `box-ordinal-group` property (http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/) - and if you can't make it work with floats, maybe it offers some alternative of attaining the same effect. Other than that, of course you can change the DOM order or simulate the layout by other means, but that's not advisable if you want to preserv your structure.

Answer (score 0):

reorganize your DOM so that Add is before View and float them to right.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned, i dont have access to the html. only css